# Invalid block tag on line 5: 'else'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: python, django, if-statement

I am getting this irritating error and even after half an hour i am not able to resolve it. In beginning of my index.html file i am putting this code.

```
{% load static %}

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
      {% extends 'dashboard.html' %}
{% else %}
       // Some other html 
{% endif %}
```

dashboard.html is in the same directory as of index.html.I would love to get corrected.